# how to compare oledb datareader with a textbox data?

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

i want to compare oledb datareader data with a textbox data something like this cod.

i have textbox named textbox7 ... the datareader have more than one mobile_no

```
OleDbCommand ol_com = new OleDbCommand();
OleDbDataReader reader;
ol_com.CommandText = "select [mobile_no] from student_info";
reader = ol_com.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.Equals(textbox7.text))
{
  up_st_lbl2.Text = "error";
 }
 else 
 {
    //do something
 }
```

any one can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare the actual OleDbDataReader object with the TextBox string value, which will obviously not return true ever. You need to compare the column value of your query with the text box. You might also consider putting a WHERE clause in your sql to filter out unnecessary rows. Please read this article to get a basic understanding of how to perform data access with MS Access - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971485.aspx

```
if ((string) reader["[mobile_no]") == textbox7.Text)
{
// error
{
```

Comment: thank you for your answer ... your answer gives me error say 'No data exists for the row/column.'? can you solve this for me please

Comment: i solve this error know it gives error 'indexoutofrange exception was unhandled' in [card_id]?